# Record details issue in community

Tags: community

I have created Object pages:

[image]

I have added record banner & record information tab, record details isnot working

[image]

I need to see the record details. how to do it.

Please explain the steps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This message will be displayed if there are no records in the org for that object, or you do not have access to any records for that object, or there is underlying configuration that is incomplete or misconfigured. Try creating some test records in the org and then view the page in builder again. It should display one of the records if they exist.

Answer (score 0):

Record Detail page needs Record Id to show it. Current view is community builder view and no record Id is being provided at this moment; so it renders this view. You need to pass id. So, either open this detail page in community having id in URL or open it in preview mode and pass parameter `recordId` in parameter.

Comment: yes,,,,Instead of recordid, cant we display like a form?.........

Comment: sorry...i don't fallow...can u elaborate?

Comment: If record is available in classic..automatically record will come up in community.. no need to pass id

Comment: Yes..u have right